# Handle a failed registerForActivityResult

Tags: java, android

Good day

I'm trying to change all my startActivityForResult to registerForActivityResult. When I used startActivityForResult I passed a int to the function to handle "no file selected"

```
public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent)
```

and used

```
if (i != 1) {Toast.makeText(this, "Recipe not loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

say when the user presses the back button instead of selecting a file

In my new code my app crashes when I do not select a file

Here is my old function:

```
 /* access modifiers changed from: protected */
    public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(i, i2, intent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewRecipe);
        textView.setText(" ");
        this.Ingredients.clear();
        this.Measurement.clear();
        this.Amount.clear();
        this.Recipe.clear();
        this.TerminationWords.add("METHOD");
        this.TerminationWords.add("METODE");
        this.TerminationWords.add("PREPARATION");
        this.TerminationWords.add("VOORBEREIDING");
        this.TerminationWords.add("INSTRUCTIONS");
        this.TerminationWords.add("INSTRUKSIES");
        if (i != 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recipe not loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (i2 == -1) {
            try {
                // read text file here
    }catch (IOException unused) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load recipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

And here is my new function:

```
showRecipeActivity = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tViewRecipe);
                        textView.setText(" ");
                        MainActivity.this.Ingredients.clear();
                        MainActivity.this.Measurement.clear();
                        MainActivity.this.Amount.clear();
                        MainActivity.this.Recipe.clear();
                        MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("METHOD");
                        MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("METODE");
                        MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("PREPARATION");
                        MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("VOORBEREIDING");
                        MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("INSTRUCTIONS");
                        MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("INSTRUKSIES");
                        try {
                            //Read text file here
                        } catch (IOException unused) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load recipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }


        );
```

How I call the showRecipeActivity:

```
private void showRecipe() {
            showRecipeActivity.launch("text/*");
}
```

I tried to add a try/catch block in the "public void onActivityResult(Uri result)" function, I also tried a try/catch over the showRecipeActivity.launch("text/*") call both to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
showRecipeActivity = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                        if(result != null) {
                            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tViewRecipe);
                            textView.setText(" ");
                            MainActivity.this.Ingredients.clear();
                            MainActivity.this.Measurement.clear();
                            MainActivity.this.Amount.clear();
                            MainActivity.this.Recipe.clear();
                            MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("METHOD");
                            MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("METODE");
                            MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("PREPARATION");
                            MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("VOORBEREIDING");
                            MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("INSTRUCTIONS");
                            MainActivity.this.TerminationWords.add("INSTRUKSIES");
                            try {
                                //Read recipe here
                            } catch (IOException unused) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load recipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recipe not loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }


        );
```

Add:

```
if(result!= null){
//code here
}else{
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recipe not loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Do not use if () {} else {}. As one has to scroll down to see what happens for the else. Do without the else: `if(result==null) return; // your code here.`